# ExtJS 3.4 Ext.ux.form.fileuploadfield buttonOnly does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, extjs, file-upload

I'm struggling to get the Ext.ux.form.fileupoadfield extension working correctly in ExtJS 3.4.
Functionally, everything works just the way it should.

I want the inputfield to be a button without any text, just an icon. I have added the iconCfg with my icon class to the component, which adds the icon, but not to the browse button. Instead, it adds another button with the icon on it next to the browse button. When you mouse over the browse button, both the icon button and the browse button are highlighted. When you mouse over the icon button, the browse button does not get highlighted.

When you click the icon button, the file window does not appear, only the actual browse button works. I have put the "buttonOnly" property of the component to true, which only hides the readonly text field (while still taking up space, messing up the layout). The default browse button is still displayed along with my icon button, the "No file chosen" dialog is still visible.

No warnings or errors are thrown by the way.

**The example along with the source file:**
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/VANSTYN/JavaScript-ExtJS-V3-3.4.1/share/ext-3.4.1/examples/form/file-upload.html

I basically want to accomplish the layout in the second example, but with an icon instead of the text button.

My code:

```
{
            xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
            id: 'filedata',
            buttonOnly: true,
            hideLabel: true,
            buttonCfg: {
                iconCls: 'icon-excel-import'
            }

}
```

What it actually looks like:

[image: Buggy uploadfield]

The same, but with buttonOnly set to false:

[image: Buggy uploadfield]

The entire layout of the component looks messed up. I have simply used the source script from this example, and the code I am using for the component looks correct to me. Why is this component this buggy for me while it works just fine in the example over at Sencha?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the css file... I already suspected as much.

For those interested, here is the full source with the js and css files:
http://trac.geoext.org/browser/ext/3.4.0/examples/ux/fileuploadfield?rev=2740